# Tmax of parallel reactions/Steady state reactions

Tags: reaction-mechanism, kinetics, rate-equation

> Below are four reactions, to this experiment inhibitor is added so that k$_3$ = $0$ (but the other reactions are unaffected) calculate [D] when the reaction is over. The initial concentration of A is $0.016$M.
>
> A → B              k$_1$= $0.110$ s$^{-1}$
>
> A → C              k$_2$= $0.025$ s$^{-1}$
>
> B → C               k$_3$= $75.2$ s$^{-1}$
>
> C → D              k$_4$= $17.2$ s$^{-1}$

I am having trouble understanding how to solve this problem. I know the first step is to calculate the time $t$ however I do not know how to apply what I know from other problems to this one.

I know that t$_{max}$ will be when dD/dt = $0$, and if I remove reaction $3$, then I get that dD/dt = k$_2$[A]. This is where I get confused.

Should I now replace [A] with the integrated equation of A from the reactions, meaning:

-dA/dt = [A](k$_1$ + k$_2$) => ln[A]-ln[A]$_0$ = -(k$_1$ + k$_2$)t => [A]=[A]$_0$e$^{-(k_1 + k_2)t}$

But then if I substitute that into dD/dt = k$_2$[A] =$0$ then I can't solve for $t$

How would one solve this?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

Have I derived the wrong expression for dD/dt?

I get that: dB/dt = $k_1$[A], dC/dt=k$_2$[A]-k$_4$[C], dD/dt= k$_4$[C]

However, here I have to set both dB/dt and dC/dt equal to zero. So that means that [A] has to be zero and that would in turn lead to [C] also having to be zero. So how should the expression be derived?

Comment: Is this the same problem as before? Or did I misread the question the first time? If you write the full reaction, and the the reaction goes to completion, what is the concentration of D? Isn't that just stoichiometry?

Comment: @Zhe this is not the same question as before, then a time was given and I think I managed to solve it. Also I don't quite understand what you mean, here I have to calculate a time t in order to determine the concentration of D when then reaction goes to completion.

Comment: Why? Is not completion determined fully by the amount of A? Why are we even bothering to treat this as a kinetics problem?

Comment: Oh, I see because k3 = 0 now...

Comment: You won't be able to solve for a time when dD/dt = 0. It should be $t = \infty$. To first order, A is partitioned between B and C. There is no backward reaction, so the relative rates determine what becomes B and what becomes D.

Comment: @Zhe But won't D reach its maximum value at the completion of the reaction? In other problems I have seen that dD/dt=0 is used to derive an expression for tmax.. it seems this cannot be used here but how do I use t = infinity?

Comment: You can't use steady-state approx on B because it is a product if k3=0 not an intermediate.

Comment: But won't D reach maximum when A is consumed? You could also just set $t=\infty$ and evaluate. That should just work.

Comment: @Andrew Oh yeah of course, so then only C is an intermediate. In that case my expression for dD/dt seems to be correct..

Comment: @Zhe I'm sorry but I don't understand how to "evaluate" it. What equation should I use if I want to evaluate it when t = ∞? I apologize if this is an obvious solution but I am really struggling to understand it all

Comment: Based on what you wrote, you can evaluate [A] by taking the limit $t \rightarrow \infty$. If it's not clear, I don't think I understand what you're asking.

Comment: The amount of D produced eventually is the fraction that goes to C initially, i.e. $k_2/(k_1+k_2) $ and as C only goes to D the amount of D is that initially in A, i.e $A_0$ multiplied by the fraction $k_2/(k_1+k_2) $. You should also realise that C appears with the rate constant $k_1+k_2$  although you do not need this.

Comment: @porphyrin Thank you it became much clearer now!